# 554 5.7.1 <info@domain.com> Relay access denied Relay access denied

Tags: email

I am using the [griddler](http://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler) gem with SendGrid to receive incoming emails. I have set it up and successfully pointed my mx record to mx.sendgrid.net. When sending an email, some of them work but others get the following error.

```
554 5.7.1 <info@domain.com>  Relay access denied Relay access denied
```

I have purchased this domain from namecheap. Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you set up a proper Parse hook as described in: http://sendgrid.com/blog/receiving-email-in-your-rails-app-with-griddler/ ?

Comment: Yeah i have done that and receive emails. But when I try to send them by consistently it errors with that message.